# How to select default dropdown value select2 inside bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I have a Bootstrap modal with a select2 dropdown inside it:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            ...
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-md-3">Artist</label>
                 <div class="col-md-9">
                    <select name="artist" class="form-control" id="dropartist"></select>
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

function when bootrap called to set dropdown:

```
$('#modal_form').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  console.log("OK");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //data: {dropartist: dropartist},
    url: 'Manage/get_artists',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      var $el = $("#dropartist");
      $el.empty(); // remove old options
      var len = response.length;
      for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){

        var id = response[i]['id'];
        var name = response[i]['name'];

        $el.append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Function to load data to Bootstrap:

```
function edit(id){
  save_method = 'update';
  $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
  $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
  $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string    
  //Ajax Load data to modal
  $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo base_url('Manage/edit')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

      $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
      $('[name="name"]').val(data.name);
      $("#dropartist").val(data.artistid).trigger("change"); //select dropdown default 
      $('[name="reason"]').val(data.reason);
      $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
      $('.modal-title').text('Edit Artist'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
  });
}
```

I try to select the dropdown, but it's doesn't work. 
How do I solve this problem? Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: we don't know it as you write its doesn't work, try to put error

Comment: But, in my console no message error sir.

Comment: are you sure you get data back from the ajax call?

Comment: Yes sir, everything ok, except for dropdown. The value that I want not selected.

Comment: shouldn't you call `$('[name="name"]').select2()` at some point?

Comment: Yes sir, I tried it before, still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed, I am get the all dropdown value and selecting the right value inside my php controller and pass to bootrap modal via ajax. Thanks to @KHansen for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your Select is empty and has no items to select. So first off when you want to update the select you have to insert the `<options></options>` and not set the value. So basicly `data.artistid` (or another var) must contain a html string like this

```
<option value="value-1" selected="selected">Name</option>
<option value="value-2">Name</option>
<option value="value-3">Name</option>
```

Then you have to change your jQuery to

```
$("#dropartist").html(data.artistid);
```

After that you can change the selected item.

Comment: Where should I place this code sir, before my data request?

Comment: Sorry my bad sir, please check my edited question, I use it when bootrap modal called.

Comment: @Denny I'm still confused. Are you first calling your `function edit()` and then this function opens the modal? That can't work because you would try to update the val before appending the options.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing sir, so should I set selected value after bootstrap called?

Comment: Yes, right know your trying to select something that does not exist (at this point of time).

Comment: Wow, you right sir I remove the $el.empty();  and works like a charm.

Comment: But value that I want doubled now.